# Facebook sdk getting friends using my app

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to get my friends using the same application that I'm using, I wrote the following code:

```
 new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/friends",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    /* handle the result */
                    Log.d("-@-", "graph response " + response.getJSONObject());
                }
            }



        ).executeAsync();
```

It's giving in the logcat the following error :

```
 09-14 21:05:10.096: W/FacebookSDK.Request(12520): starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for //me/friends should contain an explicit "fields" parameter.
```

Also the output in the log is :

```
09-14 21:05:10.706: D/-@-(12520): graph response {"summary":{"total_count":776},"data":[]}
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to:

```
   private void getUserFriendsFacebookIds() {

        GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/me/friends",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                   public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                   /* handle the result */
                   Log.d("-@-", "graph response " + response.getJSONObject());
    if (response.getError() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "User data error: " + response.getError(), response.getError().getException());
        } else {
            setUserFriends(response.getRawResponse());
        }
            }
          }
        );

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

    }

private void setUserFriends(String json) {

    FacebookFriendsInfo ff = new Gson().fromJson(json, FacebookFriendsInfo.class);

    Log.i(TAG, "User friends: " + ff);
    ...
}
```

To parse response try to use GSON library.

```
public class FacebookFriendsInfo {


    public List<Friend> data = new ArrayList<Friend>();


    public String getIds() {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (Friend f : data) {

            sb.append(String.format("%d,", f.id));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FacebookFriendsInfo{" +
                "data=" + data +
                '}';
    }

    public class Friend {
        public long id;
        public String name;


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Friend{" +
                    "id=" + id +
                    ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yep the error is gone, but the graph response is still the same, I thnik there are no friends using my app for now. Thanks man :D

Comment: yeah. upvoting this one, as it´s more specific. of course you don´t get any friends if they did not authorize your app yet :)

Comment: @Monzer Yaghi Facebook allows you to create temporary/fake accounts and connect them to your application.

Comment: If there is data inside the "data" array, how can I get them ?

Comment: @Monzer Yaghi Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this API call: `me/friends?fields=name`

See "Declarative Fields" in the changelog for v2.4: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Comment: it's giving me "graph response null"

Comment: the answer of dieter_h is actually more specific. of course you can´t just use the api call like that in the android sdk, my answer is just the direct call as you would test it in the api explorer.

Comment: If there is data inside the "data" array, how can I get them ?